# Install Windows from CentOS?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I am working on a virtual machine and I can start it or power it off any time, boot from cd-drom. Now the problem is they only have Linux OS and I would like to install Windows, something like dual boot.

Is there a way to do this ? I thought something to make a partition and then boot from that partition but is that possible ?

Comment: when you power off the virtual machine you are working on, what's the hosting system? Did you meant to say you can power off also the actual machine? if so, why do you mention you use a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes and then I can start it again... Here i have a screenshot how it looks http://oi42.tinypic.com/2ue09wi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Backup CentOS, boot from the Windows install CD, install it(which will wipe out CentOS), then create a new partition, install CentOS to the partition, and restore the data you backed up.

Comment: they only have linux that's the problem. they had windows before but now they don't I tried to contact them but they don't answer my question regarding windows image.